# OpenLayers not rendering map TMS tiles on print in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, gis, openlayers

In my Angular app i want to create pdf document of map image and polylines on it. But map tiles are not getting rendered on canvas when i try to create a pdf document from html element.

My code is like this.
First i create a map my inserting tiles into html element (Standard way) and map works great.

```
<div id="map" (contextmenu)="openContextMenu($event); false"></div>
```

And then on a button click i call a generatePdf function

```
<p-button type="button" class="btn" icon="fas fa-print" (click)="generatePdf('test')" label="Print"></p-button>


    async generatePdf(title: string): Promise<void> {
        const docDefinition: TDocumentDefinitions = {
            content: [
                { text: title, style: 'header' },
                { text: 'Additional Information', style: 'subheader' },
                {
                    image: await this.getImageMapUrl(),
                    width: 500,
                },
            ],
            styles: {
                header: { fontSize: 18, bold: true },
                subheader: { fontSize: 14, bold: true, margin: [0, 10, 0, 5] },
            },
        };
        pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).open();
    }

    public async getImageMapUrl(): Promise<any> {
        this.map.getView().setCenter(fromLonLat([15, 46]))
        const element = document.getElementById('map');

        if (!element) {
            throw new Error(`Element with id not found.`);
        }
        const exportOptions: Partial<Options> = {
            useCORS: true,
            imageTimeout: 100
        };
        const canvas = await html2canvas(element, exportOptions);
        return canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    }
```

The file that gets generated has polyline layers printed but not map tiles.
I tried with jsPDF, like in the docs, but its still not rendering tiles/canvas. Any ideas?
[image]

Comment: How have you defined the tile source?  Does it include the crossOrigin option?

Comment: Thank you!
The solution was adding crossOrigin: 'anonymous' to source of TileLayer class
```
const l = new TileLayer({
            source: new XYZ({
                url: ...
                crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
            }),
        });
```